# Override org-mode indentation function in evil insert mode

Tags: org-mode, evil, doom

How can I override the org-mode indentation function of `TAB` in `evil-insert-state-map`? I'd like it to always fold and unfold the current or parent header, and switch the indentation functionality to another keybinding.

Comment: What is the output of `C-h k` while under `evil-insert-state` in `org-mode`?

Comment: `org-cycle`. Interesting... Why isn't the visibility cycling, then...?

Comment: Found why. Please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc of `org-cycle`:

```
When point is not at the beginning of a headline, execute the global
binding for `TAB', which is re-indenting the line.  See the option
`org-cycle-emulate-tab' for details.
```

Seems setting `org-cycle-emulate-tab` to `nil` will do.

---

Relevant doc:

```
Where should ‘org-cycle’ emulate TAB.
nil         Never
white       Only in completely white lines
whitestart  Only at the beginning of lines, before the first non-white char
t           Everywhere except in headlines
exc-hl-bol  Everywhere except at the start of a headline
If TAB is used in a place where it does not emulate TAB, the current subtree
visibility is cycled.
```

---

Relevant code:

Note how when everything fails, fallback to cycle the headings (Last 4 lines).

```lisp
(cond
       ......

       ((or (eq org-cycle-emulate-tab t)
        (and (memq org-cycle-emulate-tab '(white whitestart))
             (save-excursion (beginning-of-line 1) (looking-at "[ \t]*"))
             (or (and (eq org-cycle-emulate-tab 'white)
                  (= (match-end 0) (point-at-eol)))
             (and (eq org-cycle-emulate-tab 'whitestart)
                  (>= (match-end 0) pos)))))
        (call-interactively (global-key-binding (kbd "TAB"))))
       (t
        (save-excursion
          (org-back-to-heading)
          (org-cycle))))
```

Comment: Huh... Actually, in `insert` mode, it's still indenting the headers. Can I change that as well?

Comment: @ShadowRylander That's weird. Setting `nil` works for me. I don't have doom emacs to dig further unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, fair enough; thank you kindly for the help either way!

Comment: @ShadowRylander Actually, have you ever tried `edebug`? Source code of `org-cycle` isn't that long to track. Perhaps you can find which `cond` condition is the culprit. It's what I would do if I were to have this problem.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of attaching `org-cycle` to a keychord; if that tabs as well, I'll know for sure it's the `org-cycle` function itself. From there I could just use `edebug`, as you mentioned.

Comment: Found the issue; it has something to do with `evil-insert-state`.

Comment: @ShadowRylander I see. Doom related settings?

Comment: If it is, I can't seem to find which one. What I've taken to do is simply disable `evil-mode` on insert, then reenable it when exiting the state. Slow, but works. Do you know of any way to speed up mode enabling and disabling?

Comment: @ShadowRylander That sounds inconvenient. `C-z` can switch to emacs state temporarily, but that hardly seems a nice solution. Just so you know, since you've narrowed it down to `evil-insert-state` related issue: in Spacemacs, `(lookup-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<tab>"))` evals to `nil`. I don't know what's going on with doom, since from Spacemacs setting, it doesn't make sense that `evil-insert-state` would affect `TAB` behavior. 

Comment: Hmm... `emacs-state` doesn't seem to work either, and neither does a lot of the ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542097/emacs-evil-mode-how-to-change-insert-state-to-emacs-state-automatically; would you happen to know if `evil-org-mode` could be causing the problem, if you use it? I don't think it is, since I tried again after disabled it using `use-package`.

Comment: I do use this package, enabled by Spacemacs org layer by default. I don't know where to start though, since I can't reproduce. May I ask what makes you conclude that it's a `evil-insert` issue? Which `cond` of function `org-cycle` returns `t` and why?

Comment: I'm not sure about the condition, but I concluded that it's `evil-insert` because it works in `evil-normal`, and works when `evil-mode` is disabled. Is there any way to check conclusively?

Comment: @ShadowRylander edebug: that's how I discover about the usage of the variable in my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes; forgot about it in the hubbub. I'll see what I can find using it.

Comment: Sorry about the `edebug` thing; I'm always a little hesitant to try things that may take a while. However, I seem to have found another issue: `evil-mode` doesn't seem to interact well with `emacs-lisp-mode`; it seems to randomly delete lines when trying to move with the arrow keys. I'm considering just giving up on `evil-mode` in general, and using it only when necessary.